# Unable to preview in content editor - Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have added 2 pages in the content tree - index & Home Page. It was working fine until yesterday. Unable to preview 'index' in the Content editor (CE) now.
The error message is -

> The requested document was not found

However, when I do Tools > Browse > Preview, from Sitecore Rocks, it opens fine. Also, I am able to preview 'Home Page' in CE without issue.

Following Mike's Solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537015/sitecore-the-layout-for-the-requested-document-was-not-found), I tried to add the user 'Everyone' and removing 'extranet/Anonymous'. But the changes never Save.

[image]

Why does it happen to this page alone. No changes made to web.config and I am using only master DB.

**UPDATE:**
Here is what I have observed.
When 'index' is placed outside the 'en' folder, it can be previewed. Someone suggested that Sitecore is confused by the folder name with its languages. But renaming it to Test-en, also did not work.
I also tried this. Created 'index' outside 'en' folder. Then created a copy of the same inside the 'en' with the name 'index1'. I can preview index1 now, but if 'index' is deleted, it's the same issue again.

Comment: The read permissions are set to "Deny". You should try changing that to "allow" or ensure you are logged in to the front-end (not the CE)

Comment: I did not understand what is "logging into front-end(and not the CE)". I am logged into the sitecore admin interface. When I do Require Login > Details > & edit permissions. They dont apply. Also as seen the image, The icon for 'index' is not displayed, but when I click on index, I can see the assigned icon in the right side panel. I think, both my problems are related to a common 'security' thing.

Comment: So remove the the security thing. Your image cleary shows the permissions for deny. When you preview the item you are previewing it as `extranet/anonymous`

Comment: If removing the security doesn't resolve the issue, are you able to load the page in Preview mode from the Publish ribbon?

Comment: Yes i am able to preview that in preview mode from publish ribbon. This is a clean installation and I haven't made any security settings. I tried to change the `extranet/anonymous` to `Everyone`, but the changes never applied.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen a few times. On a new instance, I don't believe it is permissions, especially if you are using SIM to install (if you aren't - try it!)

Follow these steps and it should fix your issue. Make sure all instances of your browser are closed. They are known to keep hidden instances running. Stop all those tasks. Restart your IIS instance. Log Into your sitecore site with the magical password. Preview the page. You should be able to preview and in fact get the Experience Editor.

I do agree that Sitecore is confused as to the state of that it is logged in as, that is why it is important to close all browser instances.

If you still get this error, clear your logs. Do the above steps and send me your logs. I will look at them for any oddities.

Happy Sitecoring!